# System tray icons won't pop out

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, tray

My KDE system tray icons is quite standard (time, network connection, sound, etc).

[image]

Usually, clicking on one of those icons makes a pop-up appears, and allows e.g. to select the media to mount, to change the volume, etc.
Something like this:

[image]

However, sometimes (I'm not sure what triggers it), clicking on an icon does not have any effect (beside adding a blue bar on top of it):

[image]

I feel like this happen particularly when I'm transferring large files, and the "on going task" icon is active for a long time, but could be wrong.

```
$  plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.8.6
$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.7.1
KDE Frameworks: 5.28.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Comment: Could "I feel like this happen particularly when I'm transferring large files" point to a limitation of resources?

Comment: @DKBose It could, but how can I test this?

Comment: • You could monitor resource usage with `top` when you're transferring big files: is swap being accessed or are applications such as dolphin or baloo acting up? • You could try a "light" manager such as pcmanfm (so that plasma-related aspects aren't involved) or use the terminal, if possible, to do the copying and see if the situation persists.